# yarn add react react-dom platform win32 error

Tags: reactjs

I have installed Node.js version 8.6 64 bit

When i am trying to install React dom using
yarn add react react-dom

Its giving me an error
fsevents@1.0.17: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.

Please help me in overcoming this.

Comment: Oh man this is a big issue with Windows machines. The only way I've had any luck with getting a node app running on windows is by using [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/). Download this terminal and then try again.

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: Check https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/859 for solutions